# Error (Incomplete \iffalse) with enumerate and Hebrew

Tags: enumerate, polyglossia, hebrew

I have got the following problem: Trying to have an enumerate environment in an all Hebrew document (i.e. main document language is Hebrew) causes `Incomplete \iffalse`. The same with with German as main document language works fine. What is the reason?

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[nouppercase,headsepline]{scrpage2}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{german}

%\setmainlanguage{german}
%\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\newfontfamily{\germanfont}{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{David CLM}

\begin{document}

טקסט

\begin{enumerate}
\item מבוא
\begin{enumerate}
\item מקור המובא
\item דוגמת אבי
\item המינוח מאת דיטריך בונהויפֿר
\end{enumerate}
\item התפתחות בכנסיה
\item חטא וסליחה
\item חזרה בתשובה ובשאלה
\end{enumerate}

טקסט

\end{document}
```

A run with Hebrew as the main language causes the following error:

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 28.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> test_enum.tex

The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

! Emergency stop.
<*> test_enum.tex

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

\listfiles (with German as the main language which causes no error) yields:

```
*File List*
 scrbook.cls    2010/09/17 v3.07 KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty    2010/09/17 v3.07 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2010/09/17 v3.07 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2009/03/25 v3.03 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2010/09/14 v3.06a KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
  size14.clo    1999/11/11 v1.4a NON-Standard LaTeX file (size option)
typearea.sty    2010/09/17 v3.07 KOMA-Script package (type area)
scrpage2.sty    2010/04/22 v2.5 LaTeX2e KOMA-Script package
polyglossia.sty    2010/07/27 v1.2.0a Babel replacement for XeLaTeX
etoolbox.sty    2010/09/12 v2.0a e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
makecmds.sty    2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
fontspec.sty    2010/11/17 v2.1e Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2010/11/13 v2083 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2010/10/03 v2064 L3 Experimental Naming Scheme for TeX Primitiv
es
l3basics.sty    2010/10/03 v2063 L3 Experimental basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2010/09/20 v2037 L3 Experimental Argument Expansion module
    l3tl.sty    2010/12/18 v2103 L3 Experimental Token Lists
   l3int.sty    2010/10/17 v2077 L3 Experimental Integer module
 l3quark.sty    2010/09/20 v2036 L3 Experimental Quark Commands
   l3seq.sty    2010/03/29 v1879 L3 Experimental sequences and stacks
  l3toks.sty    2010/09/20 v2037 L3 Experimental Token Registers
   l3prg.sty    2010/10/03 v2063 L3 Experimental control structures
 l3clist.sty    2010/10/09 v2071 L3 Experimental comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2010/10/03 v2063 L3 Experimental token investigation and manipu
lation
  l3prop.sty    2010/11/23 v2087 L3 Experimental Property Lists
   l3msg.sty    2010/10/02 v2052 L3 Experimental LaTeX Messages module
    l3io.sty    2010/10/03 v2063 L3 Experimental i/o module
  l3skip.sty    2010/11/23 v2088 L3 Experimental skip registers
   l3box.sty    2010/09/26 v2048 L3 Experimental Box module
l3keyval.sty    2010/04/11 v1890 L3 Experimental keyval processing
  l3keys.sty    2010/11/11 v2082 L3 Experimental key-value support
l3precom.sty    2010/02/09 v1793 L3 Experimental precompilation module
  l3xref.sty    2010/02/09 v1786 L3 Experimental cross referencing
  l3file.sty    2010/03/21 v1853 L3 Experimental file loading
    l3fp.sty    2010/12/18 v2104 L3 Experimental floating-point operations
l3luatex.sty    2010/07/18 v1985 L3 Experimental LuaTeX functions
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  xparse.sty    2010/10/13 v2073 Generic document command parser
 xkeyval.sty    2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
fontspec-patches.sty    2010/11/17 v2.1e Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/Lu
aLaTeX
fixltx2e.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2010/11/06 v0.96 provides access to latin accents and many othe
r characters in Unicode lower plane
fontspec.cfg
gloss-german.ldf    polyglossia: module for german
 babelsh.def    2009/05/07 Babel common definitions for shorthands
 Taken verbatim from babel.def (2008/07/06 v3.8l)
gloss-hebrew.ldf    polyglossia: module for hebrew
    bidi.sty    2010/09/28 v1.1.5a <commit 98> Bidirectional typesetting in pla
in TeX and LaTeX
   iftex.sty    2010/07/25 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX,
 and LuaTeX
loadingorder-bidi.def    2010/07/25 v0.5 making sure that bidi is the last pack
age loaded
xetex-bidi.def    2010/08/01 v0.8 bidi adaptations for XeTeX engine
footnote-xetex-bidi.def    2010/07/25 v0.5 bidi footnote macros for XeTeX engin
e
scrbook-xetex-bidi.def    2010/07/25 v0.3 bidi adaptations for scrbook class fo
r XeTeX engine
hebrewcal.sty    2008/07/01 v2.4 Hebrew calendar for polyglossia (adapted from 
hebcal.sty in Babel)
cal-util.def
babel-hebrewalph.def    2010/03/02 Babel definitions for Hebrew numerals
 Adapted from hebrew.ldf (2005/03/30 v2.3h)
 ***********
```

Comment: I get no error with both settings for the languages; of course, if you set German as the main language, you have to enclose the Hebrew parts between `\begin{hebrew}` and `\end{hebrew}` or `\begin{otherlanguage*}{hebrew}` and `\end{otherlanguage*}` (see the documentation of Polyglossia). There's no need to load `xltxtra`, in general. Can you give more information about your TeX system?

Comment: Please, add also the output you get by adding `\listfiles` to your document. I mean what you'll find in the log file after `*File List*`.

Comment: I understand. But I do get an error (only with Hebrew as main language) with both MiKTeX on a Windows machine and MacTeX on a Mac.

Comment: The best advice I can give you is to update your TeX distribution.

Comment: OK. Whatever was the problem, a full update fixed it.